# MySQL SUM of multiple rows from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the sum of multiple rows from 2 different tables, but somehow the result returns multiple rows.

I need to get the SUM of quotation_item_amount (group by quotation_id) and invoice_item_amount (group by invoice_id) and if I query unpaid quotation, I need to get WHERE SUM(invoice) < SUM(quotation)

So here's my sample table

```
table client_project_id
+-------------------+-----------+----------------------+
| client_project_id | client_id | client_project_title |
+-------------------+-----------+----------------------+
|         23        |     5     |        Project 1     |
|         17        |     9     |        Project 2     |
|         54        |     7     |        Project 3     |
+-------------------+-----------+----------------------+

table quotation
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
| quotation_id | client_project_id | quotation_number |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
|       1      |          23       |   Q/01/2020/001  |
|       2      |          17       |   Q/01/2020/002  |
|       3      |          54       |   Q/01/2020/003  |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+

table quotation_item
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| quotation_item_id | quotation_id | quotation_item_amount |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|         1         |     1        |          500          |
|         2         |     1        |          700          |
|         3         |     1        |          600          |
|         4         |     2        |          200          |
|         5         |     2        |          150          |
|         6         |     3        |          900          |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+

table invoice
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
|  invoice_id  | client_project_id |  invoice_number  |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
|       1      |          23       |   I/01/2020/001  |
|       2      |          17       |   I/01/2020/002  |
|       3      |          54       |   I/01/2020/003  |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+

table invoice_item
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|  invoice_item_id  |  invoice_id  |  invoice_item_amount  |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|         1         |     1        |          500          |
|         2         |     1        |          700          |
|         3         |     1        |          600          |
|         4         |     2        |          200          |
|         5         |     2        |          150          |
|         6         |     3        |          900          |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

The result that I need to obtain is:

1. SUM of quotation_item_amount and SUM of invoice_item_amount PER client_project_id
2. To query WHERE SUM(invoice) < SUM(quotation)

Here is my latest try at the query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(quotation_item.quotation_item_amount) as quot_amt, 
    SUM(invoice_item.invoice_item_amount) as inv_amt,
    data_client_project.client_project_id,
    data_client.client_name

FROM data_client_project a
LEFT JOIN quotation b ON a.client_project_id = b.client_project_id
LEFT JOIN data_client d ON a.client_id = d.client_id
LEFT JOIN invoice i ON a.client_project_id = i.client_project_id
JOIN (
        SELECT quotation_id, 
            SUM(c.quotation_item_amount) as quot_amt
        FROM quotation_item c 
        GROUP BY c.quotation_id
      ) quotitem
        ON b.quotation_id = quotitem.quotation_id
        JOIN (
            SELECT invoice_id, 
                SUM(e.invoice_item_price) as inv_amt
            FROM invoice_item e
            GROUP BY e.invoice_id
        ) invitem
        ON i.invoice_id = invitem.invoice_id
```

However, this results in multiple duplicate rows of the quotation_item_amount and invoice_item_amount.

Have tried using UNION / UNION ALL and several other queries which just do not work.
Thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: if you would include the scripts to create your tables and populate them with data, or even better if you could do that on some site like sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com and then post the link in your question it would be a lot easier for others to help you get an answer to your question. also, if you could provide an example of the result set your current query is giving you as well as an example of how it should look being sure to clearly point out the differences between the two that would help a lot as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to aggregate along two different dimensions at the same time.  The solution is to pre-aggregate along each dimension:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_client_project cp LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT q.client_project_id,
             SUM(qi.quotation_item_amount * qi.quotation_item_qty) as quot_amt
      FROM quotation q JOIN
           quotation_item qi
           ON qi.quotation_id = q.quotation_id
      GROUP BY q.client_project_id
     ) q
     USING (client_project_id) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.client_project_id,
             SUM(invoice_item_price) as inv_amt
      FROM invoice i JOIN
           invoice_item ii
           ON i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id
      GROUP BY i.client_project_id
     ) i
     USING (client_project_id);
```

Two notes about your style.

First, you are using *arbitrary* letters for table aliases.  This makes the query quite hard to follow and becomes quite awkward if you add new tables, remove tables, or rearrange the names.  Use abbreviations for the tables.  Much easier to follow.

Second, I don't really recommend `SELECT *` for such queries.  But, you can avoid duplicated column by replacing `ON` with  `USING`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this return error: Unknown column 'qi.quotation_id' in 'on clause', I'm guessing it's because of the second part?

Comment: And for the SELECT * is just for example, at real time I'm specifically selecting each column

Comment: I have edited my question to specifically SELECT 
    SUM(quotation_item.quotation_item_amount) as quot_amt, 
    SUM(invoice_item.invoice_item_amount) as inv_amt,
    data_client_project.client_project_id,
    data_client.client_name

Comment: @Charas . . . I fixed the `ON` clauses.

Comment: Thanks man! It really works as intended, however when I added WHERE i.inv_amt > q.quot_amt at the end, it does not return the correct data, or did I put it at the wrong position?

Comment: turns out there are some inv_amt or quot_amt that is NULL so that the data does not return any value on WHERE, how can I give a default 0 value if the quot_amt / inv_amt is NULL?

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment.  If you want non-matching rows to have `0` values instead of `NULL`, then use `COALESCE()` in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but your table descriptions do not include a example for `data_client` or `data_client_project` Given your example, I expect your row expansion is coming from the first 3 joins.

Make sure that the below is giving you the list of data you want first, then try joining in the calculation:

```
SELECT *
    FROM data_client_project a
    LEFT JOIN quotation b ON a.client_project_id = b.client_project_id
    LEFT JOIN data_client d ON a.client_id = d.client_id
    LEFT JOIN invoice i ON a.client_project_id = i.client_project_id;
#you may want to append the above with a limit 100 for testing.
```

Comment: Note: the above is not a complete answer. But trying to help with the information given. As `Gharbad The Weak` pointed out example data added in something like db-fiddle.com would do wonders.

Answer (score 0):

if you have duplicated  rows form the main query then add distinct for obatin a only distinct rows
and andd the where conditio for filtering the result  by quotitem.quot_amt < invitem.inv_amt

```
    SELECT distinct a.*, b.*, d.*, i.*  
    FROM data_client_project a
    LEFT JOIN quotation b ON a.client_project_id = b.client_project_id
    LEFT JOIN data_client d ON a.client_id = d.client_id
    LEFT JOIN invoice i ON a.client_project_id = i.client_project_id
    JOIN (
            SELECT quotation_id, 
                SUM(c.quotation_item_amount * c.quotation_item_qty) as quot_amt
            FROM quotation_item c 
            GROUP BY c.quotation_id
          ) quotitem  ON b.quotation_id = quotitem.quotation_id
    JOIN (
            SELECT invoice_id, 
                SUM(e.invoice_item_price) as inv_amt
            FROM invoice_item e
            GROUP BY e.invoice_id
            ) invitem  ON i.invoice_id = invitem.invoice_id
    WHERE quotitem.quot_amt < invitem.inv_amt
```